# Choosing a select few criterias for VBA filtering

Tags: excel, vba, filter

This is the code I have came up with after the array suggestion. However I am getting the error "For Each control variable on arrays must be Variant". What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
Sub Filter()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim x As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim last As Long
Dim sht As String
Dim arr(3) As String

'specify sheet name in which the data is stored
sht = "Sheet Name"

'Array
arr(3) = Array("A", "B", "C")

'change filter column in the following code
last = Sheets(sht).Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Sheets(sht).Range("A1:K" & last)

For Each x In arr
With rng
    .AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=x.Value
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = x.Value
ActiveSheet.Paste
End With
Next x

'Turn off filter
Sheets(sht).AutoFilterMode = False

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .CutCopyMode = False
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like all you are using AdvancedFilter  for is a unique list of values from column F, not 'a select few criteria only'. What was your specific question?

Comment: I may have been using it wrongly, but I have a set of values that I want as the filter criteria. But using this method will filter all the values in that column. How am I able to restrict in such a way that only the selected few values will be filtered? Thanks!

Comment: Feel free to be more specific than 'selected few values'.

Comment: So for example under Column "F", the column where I want to filter, in the raw data there are values [A to Z]. However I only want for example value A,C,E,F,H,K,Q,W,Z to be filtered and paste accordingly. How to I omit the rest of the values?

Comment: `arr = array("A", "C", "E", "F", "H", "K", "Q", "W", "Z")` and loop through like you did withe uniques from column F.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Haven't really worked with arrays. I'll test that out.